# Values of two select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Briefly Explaining my program :

I Have 3 select boxes

If the value selected by the user in the 1st box is 2 & Value selected by the user in second box is 3 (option values) then the third select box should display an array.

This code doesn't work but shows an idea:

```
if ($('#firstbox').click(function() { ($(this).val() == '2'); } &&    
    $('#secondbox').click(function() { ($(this).val() == '3'); }) {
    // Array Display here (not included the coding here, because there is no issue with this coding.. seems working fine)
}
```

I need help for the code included in if statment and  && operation for checking the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var select1 = $('#firstbox');
var select2 = $('#secondbox');

$([select1, select2]).change(function () {
    if ( select1.val() == 2 && select2.val() == 3 ) {
        // run your code here...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either bind the click event to the third select box or bind to the change event of the first two boxes and callback a common function which updates the third one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#firstbox, #secondbox").change(UpdateThird);

function UpdateThird() {
    var a = $("#firstbox").val();
    var b = $("#secondbox").val();
    if (a == 2 && b == 3) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming

```
<select id="firstbox">
  <option value="1">1</option>  
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="secondbox">
  <option value="1">1</option>  
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

script:

```
$('#secondbox, #firstbox').on('change',function(){
  if($('#firstbox').val() == 2 && $('#secondbox').val() == 3)
    alert('array display code here...');
})
```